# Jumping Point Blue Not Work - Video

Tags: video, asp.net-mvc-5, mp4

I am new in MVC and I am trying to play a video that it is  stored in my data base(SQL) in a VARBINARY(max) field. I can already to show the video in my WEB aplication, but the problem is the progres bar. It appers but does not work when I execute the jumping to another point.  I read some materials about this but I am not able to solve it. I think the problem is regarding the Buffering (start/end). Below is my code.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Media(int id)
{
    byte[] teste = null;
    string query1 = "SELECT * FROM  Movie WHERE ID = '"+id+"'";
    using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query1, connection1))
    {
        connection1.Open();
        var reader = command1.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            teste = (byte[])reader["Movie"];
        }
        connection1.Close();
    }
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(teste);
    return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, Convert.ToString(teste));

}
```

**View:**

```
    <video width="400" controls>
        <source src="@Url.Action("Media","Account",new { id = 3 })" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

The Jumping point below appears but does not work:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://forums.asp.net/t/2065545.aspx?HTML5+Audio+Seek+bar+doesn+t+work

```
    public ActionResult Media(string id)
    {
        byte[] teste = null;
        string query1 = "SELECT * FROM  Movie WHERE ID = '"+id+"'";
        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query1, connection1))
        {
          connection1.Open();
          var reader = command1.ExecuteReader();

          if (reader.HasRows)
          {
            reader.Read();
            teste = (byte[])reader["Movie"];
          }
          connection1.Close();
        }
        long fSize = teste.Length;
        long startbyte = 0;
        long endbyte = fSize - 1;
        int statusCode = 200;
        if ((Request.Headers["Range"] != null))
        {
            //Get the actual byte range from the range header string, and set the starting byte.
            string[] range = Request.Headers["Range"].Split(new char[] { '=', '-' });
            startbyte = Convert.ToInt64(range[1]);
            if (range.Length > 2 && range[2] != "") endbyte = Convert.ToInt64(range[2]);
            //If the start byte is not equal to zero, that means the user is requesting partial content.
            if (startbyte != 0 || endbyte != fSize - 1 || range.Length > 2 && range[2] == "")
            { statusCode = 206; }//Set the status code of the response to 206 (Partial Content) and add a content range header.                                    
        }
        long desSize = endbyte - startbyte + 1;
        //Headers
        Response.StatusCode = statusCode; 
        Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Accept", Response.ContentType);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", desSize.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startbyte, endbyte, fSize));


        var fs = new MemoryStream(teste,(int)startbyte, (int)desSize);
        return new FileStreamResult(fs, userFile.FileType);
    }
```